# Storing Objects in Vue Templates

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I create an object from a class in the mounted event.  I need to use this object throughout my component.

I've been using a data field to store the object (its not a JSON object, its a full on instantiated class).

Where is the best place to store this object? So I can use it throughout my component?

Comment: Why do you think the data field is not the right place? Where else do you want to store it?

Comment: I was under the impression that the data property is reactive, so I was looking for another global scope.   Maybe it knows the difference between a simple JSON object and a function type object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67080123/storing-objects-in-vue-templates#comment118572065_67080123), it sounds like you're looking for ways to declare non-reactive data, scoped to each component instance.

#### Option 1: Use an attached property

- Assign `this.VARNAME = VALUE`
- Typically done in the `created()` hook, but can be just about anywhere in the component context
- IntelliSense in IDEs may have trouble discovering this property (TypeScript will require type assertions/declarations)

*Example:*

```js
export default {
  created() {
    this.myNonReactiveProp = new MyClass()
  }
}
```

#### **Option 2:** Use a data property with [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

- `Object.freeze()` prevents the property from being reactive, but also make its *completely readonly*
- Can be useful for static data
- IntelliSense can detect this property (as it does for all `data()` properties)

*Example:*

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      myNonReactiveProp: Object.freeze(new MyClass())
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass class between vue components via plugin:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html

Install your plugin globally, you should call the class like this, for example:

```
class myClass {
    // ...
}

Vue.prototype.$myClass = new myClass;
```

OR in the component only:

```
<script>
class test {

}

export default {
    data: () => ({
        instance: new test
    }),
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.instance)
    }
}
</script>
```